# jQuery interactive map library?

Tags: javascript, jquery, imagemapster

I'm looking for a jQuery library or plugin that is a map of the United States, with rollover events and a click event that will return the state which you clicked on. I see it a lot in Flash, but never in jQuery.

Does anyone know of anything like this?

Comment: Try VectorWorkz GeoChart(http://vectorworkz.com/products/geochart/features), it has lot of built in maps, it allows you to customize and interact with the each regions and markers in the map.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Kinda like this?

http://www.outsharked.com/imagemapster

Comment: Shameless self promotion: i wrote the plugin. Feel free to contact me directly if you need any help or have trouble with it.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried http://www.clickablemaps.com/clickable-map-of-the-usa-canada/ ?

Comment: @ariel: The question didn't state that requirement, and some things are worth paying for.

Comment: maybe. but javascript maps arent worth paying for ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can also try this: http://jvectormap.owl-hollow.net/